# How to extract the menu bar of a GTK program

Tags: c, gtk

The key function of the applet is extracting the menu bar of a GTK program(after being extracted the menu bar of the original program should disappear), formatting the menu items to another form and displaying them.

I have googled for a long time but found almost nothing. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**Note that this is an *idea* nothing more nothing less.**

If you can get a pointer to the containing `GtkWindow` just walk the widget tree and check with `GTK_IS_MENU_BAR()` if the widget is a `GtkMenuBar`. If so, add a reference, detach it, reparent it, remove the additional ref.

You could have a look at the source of ubuntu's app indicator (not sure if that is the right project name) or the newly created `gtk-inspector` (formerly known as hacky `gtk-parasite`) which can inspect/modify widgets on the fly from a third party application.